# How to access the Kemap settings Preferences (Spacebar Action, Select Mouse button, etc) with python?

Tags: python, scripting, customization, startup-file

I use a python script to set up some startup preferences like this:

> bpy.context.preferences.view.show_tooltips_python = True

However, there is a particular set of preferences I don't know how to access, the ones in the Keymap section where you specify what spacebar does, what mouse click you use to select, etc.

**How can I access these settings?**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Search the source**

With Developer Extras turned on hover over the enum and  choose edit source

This will open up (for me)  `scripts/keyconfigs/blender.py`

```
    # General settings.
    col = layout.column()
    col.row().prop(self, "select_mouse", text="Select with Mouse Button", expand=True)
    col.row().prop(self, "spacebar_action", text="Spacebar Action", expand=True)
    if is_select_left:
        col.row().prop(self, "gizmo_action", text="Activate Gizmo Event", expand=True)
```

Notice there is a generic property update method `load(self, context)`

```
def load():
    from sys import platform
    from bpy import context
    from bl_keymap_utils.io import keyconfig_init_from_data

    prefs = context.preferences
    kc = context.window_manager.keyconfigs.new(IDNAME)
    kc_prefs = kc.preferences
```

Ok then to the python console

```
>>> C.preferences.keymap.active_keyconfig
'blender'

>>> C.window_manager.keyconfigs['blender'].preferences['spacebar_action'] = 2
```

will set to the third option.  The item that matches that number is available enum definition of the the Prefs class.

Comment: For your other question re choosing  keymap `bpy.ops.preferences.keyconfig_import(filepath="pathto/keymap.py")`

Comment: Thanks for both answers, I've used Edit Source before but a lot of what I see is beyond me. I don't think I would of found the answer without your help. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: NP.  Can be a tricky. There could be another way to get there, couldn't find it quickly.  (some thing akin to `ob.spacebar_action`)  Suggest look at `bl_keymap_utils.io` source