# How can I get the name of the currently active keymap?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, shortcut

I want to retrieve the name of the currently active keymap. How do I get it? `bpy.types.keymap.name` errors out. But the attribute 'name' is [available in the API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.KeyMap.html?highlight=keymap#bpy.types.KeyMap):

[image]

What I try to figure out is what keymap is currently the active one. The question is whether it's the *Blender*, *Industry Compatible* or a *Custom User Keymap*...? Do you have an idea?

[image]

Comment: Never going to be the class property.  _eg_ `bpy.types.Scene.prop` Instead will be an instance, _eg_ `bpy.context.scene.prop`. To clarify are you perhaps after the active keying set name?  Note `bpy.types.KeyMap.bl_rna.properties['name'].default` is the default value assigned to `KeyMap.name`

Comment: As batfinger said, don’t use the class property. That’s like trying to figure out what color you painted the house based on the original blueprint for it. Additionally, are you talking about the interface key map, as in keyboard key map? Or are you talking about keyframes?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas friends. I have updated my description to make it more clear. I am not try to retreive the keying set. I try to find out what keymap is currently the active one. Blender or Industry Compatible, or a custom user keymap.

Comment: Gotchya. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184422/how-to-access-the-kemap-settings-preferences-spacebar-action-select-mouse-butt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the name of the [active keymap](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PreferencesKeymap.html#bpy.types.PreferencesKeymap.active_keyconfig) via [`Preferences`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Preferences.html#bpy.types.Preferences). I'd recommend using the [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html) to figure out the attribute:

```
>>> C.preferences.keymap.
                         active_keyconfig
                         as_pointer(
                         bl_rna
                         ...

>>> C.preferences.keymap.active_keyconfig
'blender'

>>> C.preferences.keymap.active_keyconfig
'blender_27x'
```

Based on that knowledge on how to access the attribute it's pretty much straightforward to implement. Following script is an example on how to print the [`keyconfig`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PreferencesKeymap.html#bpy.types.PreferencesKeymap.active_keyconfig) to the [console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/launch/windows.html):

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
print (C.preferences.keymap.active_keyconfig)

# Alternatively
print (bpy.context.preferences.keymap.active_keyconfig)
```

Comment: @Tiles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1896/console-vs-scripting-python-constants